# Filtering images live search by caption

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble getting this code to run. I want to do a live search and hide any photos with captions that do not match the search text. I would appreciate any tips!

### HTML

[image]

### JavaScript

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bZwR.png]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be fairly efficient:

```
let $search = $('#search');
let $imgs = $('img')

$search.keyup(event => {
  let value = $search.val().toLowerCase();
  $imgs.show();
  if (value !== '') {
    $imgs.not('[title*="' + value + '"]').hide();
  }
});
```

Try it: https://jsfiddle.net/ct8jgvyd/1/

edit: code without arrow functions etc

```
var $search = $('#search');
var $imgs = $('img')

$search.keyup(function(event) {
  var value = $search.val().toLowerCase();
  $imgs.show();
  if (value !== '') {
    $imgs.not('[title*="' + value + '"]').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: You are awesome!! Basically I was making it way more complicated than it needed to be.